# Sending connection header set as keep-alive

Tags: c#, fiddler, keep-alive

I'm trying to send the same information from  my application as I send from the browser. Here is part of data captured by Fiddler:

```
POST http://something/ HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

I got stuck with this connection property. If I set the property keep-alive to true, in Fiddler I see this:

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

If I try to set the connection property to Keep-alive, I get this error:

Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.

How to write the code so that in Fiddler I can see this:

Connection: keep-alive

My full code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myUrl ");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.Accept = "*/*";
WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "myEncoding");
headers.Add("Accept-Language", "myLang");
request.Headers = headers;
request.ContentType = "myContentType";
request.Referer = "myReferer";
request.UserAgent = "myUserAgent";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "myData";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
request.GetResponse().Close();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To have your application send a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header, use the [KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) property on the `HttpWebRequest` object.

When a client knows that it is behind a proxy (like Fiddler), it *may* send a `Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive` header instead of a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header. The expectation is that a HTTP/1.1 proxy (like Fiddler) will convert that header from `Proxy-Connection` to `Connection` before passing it to the upstream server.

This "proxy renames header" pattern was introduced many years ago to attempt to workaround hangs in HTTP/1.0 servers that didn't support `Keep-Alive` properly; the idea is that the server would ignore the `Proxy-Connection` header if the outdated proxy didn't rename the header by removing the `Proxy-` prefix.

Comment: So what you are saying is that even if I see in Fiddler the Proxy-Connection header, the upstream server will see the Connection header anyway?

Comment: How do we debug it if fiddler ISN'T renaming it? Mine seems to intermittenly not rename it for the same application and same request. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't